# swagger-annotations @ApiModel and @ApiModelProporty not showing values

Tags: java, rest, swagger

I want to documentate my models but the swagger annotations are not working correctly. im using osgi btw.

In the Rest interface im using:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
```

And it works just fine when i go to the Swagger editor the descriptions appears.

But when I use the :

```
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
```

does not work. I got to swagger editor, and paste de yaml there and there is no descriptions on the fields/model.

im using the dependecy:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

example how im using:
Model:

```
@ApiModel(description = "foo - extends FooBase", parent = 
FooBase.class)
public class foo extends FooBase {
```

Property:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "description")
private String typeDescription;
```

How it shows on yaml:

```
 "typeDescription" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
```

swagger ui:

```
typeDescription string
```

The inheritance is not working too I think, because in swagger editor the FooBase shows like this in the swagger editor shows like this:

```
FooBase:
  type: object
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
    description:
      type: string
  discriminator:
    propertyName: type
CreateFooBaseRequest:
  type: object
  properties:
    fooBase:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/FooBase'
CreateFooBaseResponse:
  type: object
  properties:
    fooBase:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/FooBase'
```

but in the Foo class extending FooBase it appears:

```
allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FooBase'
```

there are 2 classes extending FooBase. Ex:

```
@ApiModel(description = "foo",
    subTypes = {Foo.class, FooTwo.class})
```

note that this is an example...

but its not working...

Comment: Hey were you able to figure this out? Looks like you're importing v3 but using annotations that are only in the previous version.

Comment: Hey, Im using contract first now, so I dont have any problem rn.